# PayPal Button with Form Submission - Best Practice

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, session, paypal

I have a website where I want the form data to be submitted only if I know the customer has paid via the PayPal button. Right now I have it at the point where they can pay and I verify it (via IPN) and that's about it.

I'm looking for some ideas on the best way to approach this? I was thinking that when the IPN verifies I can insert a column into the DB saying "paid" and store some information in the session. You can then only access the form if that data is in the session. Once the form has been completed I can update the status from "paid" to "completed" and remove the session data. I would remove the session data because a customer can pay as many times as they like with different form data each time.

Any other ideas? Also, this isn't a site where you would log in.

To sum it up, I want the customer to pay first (and I know they paid) then fill out a form.

Comment: what's in the form? usually people fill in the form, click pay, you check via IPN that they have paid - if not chuck out the form details or what ever. I guess you could ask them to pay, once paid send them a url with an id to the form page to fill in.

Comment: @Dagon Few textboxes and and image upload. You approach is what I'm looking for but I can't seem to get there.

Comment: whats the particulate sticking point?

Comment: @Dagon well with a paypal button it takes you to their site so submitting the form and paying at the same time wont work. with regards to paying and passing an id in a url to fill out the form, just a random id that I generate and store in the db? I guess that way it's more of an item id thats tied to a payment?

Comment: you can submit form to your server, process their submissions then send them on to paypal via curl. or have a page that confirms their submission then says click here now to pay

Comment: Ah yeah, I guess I'm just too caught up doing it one way. Maybe I could submit the form and store the record in the db as "not paid" and have a transaction id stored too. I can then direct them to the paypal button with a pass through variable of transaction id. I can then verify with ipn and update the db from "not paid" to "paid" on that transaction id.

Comment: as a customer, i would prefer not being asked to pay first.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Thanks for the ideas. Looks like I just needed to chat with someone to start thinking about it another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any login mechanism, I would request an email aswell when paying, Store the email + paymentID (unique PK) in the DB, when payment comes back through IPN, email the customer with a secret passkey, you can only move forward with that passkey.

In my opinion sessions are a problem to use for paying user. what happens if that user's computer crashs right after he paid. He has no way to access his product. An email + secret passkey would enable him to